# Capture Google Search Term and ResultStats with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have built a very simple scraper using Scrapy. For the output table, I would like to show the Google News search term as well as the Google resultstats value.

The information I would like to capture is showing in the source of the Google page as

```
<input class="gsfi" value="Elon Musk">
```

and

```
<div id="resultStats">About 52,300 results</div>
```

I have already tried to include both through `('input.value::text')` and `('id.resultstats::text')`, which did not work, however. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this situation?

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws']

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
        item = {
            'search_title': quote.css('input.value::text').extract(),
            'results': quote.css('id.resultstats::text').extract(),
            }
        yield item
```

Comment: Can you give us an example URL?

Comment: Please find enclosed: https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pages renders differently when you access it with Scrapy.

The search field becomes:

`response.css('input#sbhost::attr(value)').get()`

The results count is:

`response.css('#resultStats::text').get()`

Also, there is no `quote` class on that page.

You can test this in the scrapy shell:

`scrapy shell -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False "https://www.google.com/search?q=elon+musk&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015&tbm=nws"`

And then run those 2 commands.

[EDIT]
If your goal is to get **one** item for each URL, then you can do this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = {
        'search_title': response.css('input#sbhost::attr(value)').get(),
        'results': response.css('#resultStats::text').get(),
    }
    yield item
```

If your goal is to extract every *result* on the page, then you need something different.

Comment: That works perfectly in the terminal, many thanks. Is there a way to also include the Scrapy shell part in the regular code? The CSV files I am creating through the terminal are still empty...

Comment: Thanks again for the amended post. That is exactly what I was looking for an has helped a lot to proceed

Comment: In the future, double check your pages using `scrapy shell`. Inside the shell you can run `view(response)` and it will show you the HTML received by Scrapy in your browser.

Comment: One quick and final point - if I would like to add the search ranges as well, why does `'search_dates': response.css('div#sbhost::attr(aria-label)').get(),'` not work? The code it refers to is `<div aria-label="1 Jan 2015 – 31 Dec 2015">`, which is very similar to `value`

Comment: @M.S. That value does not exist in the HTML received by Scrapy. Test it in scrapy shell. You might be able to extract it from the URL - `d_min%3A1%2F1%2F2015%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2015` but that is off-topic to this specific question. If you need data that is only available in the full  Javascript version of the website, then you should investigate [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/).